# Is it possible to upgrade a notebook with a i3 380um to an i5 430m processor?

Tags: cpu, upgrade

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 11 0328CTO (intel HM55 chipset) that came with a i3 380UM, which is a low power 11W processor. I wonder if i can upgrade that to a i5 430M, which is the same socket, but is 35W tdp.

Comment: CPU's aren't the easiest component to upgrade on notebooks, you have to crack the laptop open, replace the CPU (which may be soldered in sometimes), and hope the laptop doesn't melt from the extra heat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can upgrade your processor to i5 430M on the Intel HM55 Chipset which you have. [Here](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Intel-Core-i3-i5-i7-Processors-Arrandale.25085.0.html) is a confirmation of the chipset working well with i3/i5/i7 processors.
- Make sure you get it done by a professional or have a look at something like [this](http://www.pcworld.com/article/148910/replace_your_laptops_cpu.html).
- For other safety factors, just check your passive cooling system and check your PSU if has the capacity to give an output with extra power. Because your motherboard definitely supports a power change. Most laptop vendors design their hardware for flexibility.
- Here is the [Manual](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/75y6925_01.pdf&ei=6bY9UPikHYnzrQfPlIAI&usg=AFQjCNFV2psVPp_1LB6YVes10V-zcOIqYw&sig2=zRanYFZ1BKLAybqjDajl5w) to show you how to open it up.

Comment: i guess i will give up on this, im afraid my notebook fan will be on all the time, or it will overheat. i guess it's not designed for this processor.